# launch file in C++

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I want to find any solution for launching file like roslaunch in C++, is there any one help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112556/launch-file-in-c++/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2013-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you want to launch a roslaunch file from a C++ application?

I don't think there for C++ there is a roslaunch API such as for Python, but I guess you can run roslaunch as a second process from within your C++ application.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2013-12-22**:
So how can I do that?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-25**:
There are many ways to do it.  That's pure c++ please look on c++ forums for how to do that.